# Copying entire Firefox profiles

Tags: windows, firefox

I'm trying to transfer people from old machines over to new ones, and I was trying to debate the best way to transfer their Firefox bookmarks. I know the recommended method by Mozilla is to just create a backup of the bookmarks and then importing them on the new machine. I want to be able to create a one-click solution if I can so my idea was to just copy the entire %appdata%/Mozilla/Firefox directory to another drive and then place it on the new machine.

I know that I'll absolutely have to grab the profiles.ini file, but are there any other pitfalls/necessary files that I've missed in doing it this way?

Comment: See: [Profile Backup](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_backup) & [Moving your profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder)

Comment: Well I understand how to backup the profile. I was hoping to avoid having to open firefox on each machine and rather create a script that could accomplish this. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: I see, what about [this script](http://www.howtogeek.com/52049/how-to-easily-automate-your-firefox-profile-backup-with-batch-files/)? You can probably modify it a little bit to suit your needs. Also, regarding your question (`any other necessary files?`): You can take a look at the [content of the Profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Files_and_folders_in_the_profile) to make sure which files you want to backup and which files are not necessary.

Comment: It looks like script is just copying the profiles directory so I think it'll work. I sure appreciate your help.

Comment: Report back if the script is working and achieving the goal; if so, I'll add it here as a backup.

Comment: The script used 7zip and had some weird temporary places it saved the files. Here is the main line of the script that worked XCOPY "%APPDATA%\Mozilla" %TEMP% /E /V /C /H /Y

Comment: Glad it helped you nonetheless. Please add your own answer - what you have done + the code, and accept it as an answer; it might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the command to copy the Firefox profile folder to a folder on the desktop. It is important to grab the profiles.ini file and not just the profile itself because the ini file tells firefox where the profile is located.

```
XCOPY "%APPDATA%\Mozilla" %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\FirefoxProfile /E /V /C /H /Y
```

And then to place it back on the computer:

```
XCOPY %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\FirefoxProfile "%APPDATA%\Mozilla" /E /V /C /H /Y
```